# How can I find original messages by subject, without corresponding "RE" replies?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

How can I search my Outlook archives for messages with a given subject, but retrieve *only* original messages?  I'd like to avoid all replies where the subject line begins with "Re:" or "RE:".

When I enter `subject:"Voice Mail"` in the search box, it successfully finds all of those messages, but they are buried in a sea of replies with the subject line `Re: Voice Mail`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining it with another search option and a `NOT` operator should do this:

```
subject:"Voice Mail" NOT subject:"Re:"
```